# How can I draw a 3D cross-section of a 3-torus embedded in 4D Euclidean space?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I have a $3$-torus ($\mathbf S^1\times\mathbf S^1\times \mathbf S^1$) embedded in 4D Euclidean space. How can I draw the cross-section of this $3$-torus cut by a 3D Euclidean space in an arbitrary direction? The equations are:

$$\begin{align*}
x &= (r + (t + d\cos\,a)\cos\,b)\cos\,c\\
y &= (r + (t + d\cos\,a)\cos\,b)\sin\,c\\
z &= (t + d\cos\,a)\sin\,b\\
w &= d\sin\,a
\end{align*}$$

where $x,y,z,w$ are the orthogonal coordinates in 4D space, $r,t,d$ are the  radii of three circles, and $a,b,c$ denote the angles of the point with respect to the three circles.

Comment: Very interesting first question.

Comment: I find very useful to solve this kind of problems by solving first a similar question with one dimension less, for example a 2D circle "floating" in 3D, and find (draw) its intersection with an arbirary plane. The idea is try to solve this other problem with techniques that can be easily extended to more dimensions. Hope that helps for the moment.

Comment: See https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/slicedHypersurface.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take $r=1, t=5, d=10$ for example:

```
r = 1; t = 5; d = 10;
```

The parametric equation for the 3-torus is given by:

```
torus3 = {(r + (t + d Cos[a]) Cos[b]) Cos[c],
          (r + (t + d Cos[a]) Cos[b]) Sin[c],
          (t + d Cos[a]) Sin[b], d Sin[a]};
```

Suppose the plane is determined by its normal $\mathbf n$ and a point $\mathbf o$ on it:

```
\[DoubleStruckN] = Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 4]]
\[DoubleStruckO] = RandomReal[{-.5, .5}, 4]
```

> ```
> {0.0266919, 0.556735, 0.561821, 0.611302}
> {-0.4925, 0.182885, -0.174828, 0.394413}
> ```

So the cross section gives a constraint on $a, b, c$, which is $(\text{torus3}-\mathbf{o})\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$, which then defines a contour surface `paraRegion` in 3D Euclidean space (didn't take the full $[0, 2\pi]$ ranges, so later we can see some inner structure of the cross section surface):

```
paraRegion = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[(torus3 - \[DoubleStruckO]).\[DoubleStruckN] == 0],
  {a, .4 π, 2π - .93 π}, {b, 0, 2 π-.1 π}, {c, 0, 2 π - .2 π},
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{a, b, c, f}, Hue[b, c, a]],
  PlotPoints -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 2,
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[{Thickness[.01], GrayLevel[.7]}],
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &},
  MeshStyle -> {RGBColor[1, .5, .5], RGBColor[.5, 1, .5], RGBColor[.5, .5, 1]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {a, b, c})]
```

[image: initial contour surface]

Thanks to the plane, we can reduce the cross section into 3D Euclidean space:

```
crossEq = RotationMatrix[{\[DoubleStruckN], {0, 0, 0, 1}}].torus3 // Most
```

So we can further transform the feasible $(a,b,c)$ set `paraRegion` to the cross section surface we want:

```
Cases[paraRegion,
   GraphicsComplex[pts_, others_,
     opts1___, VertexNormals -> vn_, opts2___] :>
    GraphicsComplex[
     Function[{a, b, c}, Evaluate[crossEq]] @@ # & /@ pts,
     others, opts1, opts2], ∞][[1]] // Graphics3D[#,
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral"] &
```

[image: 3-torus with cut-away]

## Remark

Please beware that there are disadvantages of the above method, because `Polygon`s in the cross section surface are directly inherited from the feasible parameter surface. To make sure this is correct, an assumption has to be made that the cross section surface must be continuous over the whole of `paraRegion`.

Comment: Wow,thanks very much! It is really beautiful!

Comment: @ShenghanJiang You're welcome! Good first question!

Comment: * brain explodes *

Answer (score 14):

We can use the result of

```
gb = FullSimplify[
         GroebnerBasis[{x == (r + (t + d Cos[a]) Cos[b]) Cos[c], 
                        y == (r + (t + d Cos[a]) Cos[b]) Sin[c], 
                        z == (t + d Cos[a]) Sin[b], w == d Sin[a], 
                        Cos[c]^2 + Sin[c]^2 == 1, Cos[b]^2 + Sin[b]^2 == 1, 
                        Cos[a]^2 + Sin[a]^2 == 1}, {x, y, z, w},
                       {Cos[c], Sin[c], Cos[b], Sin[b], Cos[a], Sin[a]}]]
```

to yield the implicit Cartesian equation for the $3$-torus:

```
t4[d_, r_, t_][x_, y_, z_, w_] = First[gb];
```

(Some people seem intimidated by the use of `GroebnerBasis[]`, but here its only purpose is for eliminating parameters. Here's a simpler example of its use:  `First[GroebnerBasis[{x == Cos[t], y == Sin[t], Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2 == 1}, {x, y}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]] == 0`, which yields the equation of a circle.)

We can then slice this torus with a hyperplane parametrized by its normal and its distance from the origin, like so:

```
With[{d = 10, t = 5, r = 1, (* radii *)
      nrm = Normalize[{1, -1, 1, -1}], h = 4 (* hyperplane parameters *)}, 
 ContourPlot3D[(t4[d, r, t][\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ], \[FormalW]] /. 
                Thread[{\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ], \[FormalW]} -> 
                RotationTransform[{nrm, {0, 0, 0, 1}}][{x, y, z, h}]]) == 0 // Evaluate,
               {x, -15, 0}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
               BoundaryStyle -> Opacity[1/2, Gray], BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
               ContourStyle -> Opacity[3/4, ColorData["Legacy", "Mint"]], 
               Lighting -> "Neutral", MeshStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotPoints -> 20]]
```

[image: slice of 3-torus]

To appreciate this approach, contrast this with a low-dimensional version:

```
t3[p_, q_][x_, y_, z_] := (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + p^2 - q^2)^2 - 4 p^2 (x^2 + y^2)

With[{p = 3, q = 1, nrm = Normalize[{1, -2, 3}], h = 1},
     {ContourPlot[(t3[p, q][\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]] /. 
                  Thread[{\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]} -> 
                  RotationTransform[{nrm, {0, 0, 1}}][{x, y, h}]]) == 0 // Evaluate,
                  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                  ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[1, 1]]],
      ContourPlot3D[t3[p, q][x, y, z] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
                    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[1, 1]],
                    Mesh -> None, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, nrm.{x, y, z} < h]]}
            // GraphicsRow]
```

[image: toric sections]

---

Here's a less spherical-looking cross-section of a different $3$-torus, with a convenient cut-away to display the inner structure:

```
With[{d = 9, t = 6, r = 3, nrm = Normalize[{1, 3, 1, 3}], h = 2}, 
  ContourPlot3D[(t4[d, r, t][\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ], \[FormalW]] /. 
                Thread[{\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ], \[FormalW]} -> 
                RotationTransform[{nrm, {0, 0, 0, 1}}][{x, y, z, h}]]) == 0 // Evaluate,
                {x, -16, 16}, {y, -16, 16}, {z, -16, 16}, 
                BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
                ContourStyle -> Directive[ColorData["Legacy", "PowderBlue"],
                                          Specularity[2/3, 20]],
                Lighting -> "Neutral", MaxRecursion -> 1, 
                MeshStyle -> Map[Directive[GrayLevel[1/10], Glow[#], Specularity[1, 15]] &,
                                 {Magenta, Orange, Cyan}], 
                Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 20}, PlotPoints -> 15, 
                RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0 || z < 0]]] /.
  Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest]
```

[image: another 3-torus cross-section]

Comment: +1 never used `GroebnerBasis` before.

Comment: @Silvia, it's a very useful thing. If you know in advance that your parametrized (hyper)surface is *algebraic*, you can then use `GroebnerBasis[]` for eliminating the parameters and get an implicit Cartesian equation.

Comment: I have heard of it from some [automated theorem proving topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu's_method_of_characteristic_set), but not really understand it. (Not really understand any *algebra* things anyway O__O"…)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, although the concept of Groebner Basis is hard for me to understand

Comment: @Shenghan, as I said to Silvia, just think of it as a way to eliminate the parameters in your parametric equations.