# Transcendental equation inside another equation when 3D plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have been trying to solve this plotting problem myself, and I have received a lot of very useful advice from here on Stack Exchange - but I am now at a complete loss as to how to achieve the plot I want. I am trying to do a 3D plot of the equation `z = -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2y + x)/t]]` where y is defined by the transcendental equation `y = Tanh[(2y + x)/t]`. Specifically the relation between the two equations is that `y = - ∂z/∂x`.

In particular, `y = Tanh[(2y + x)/t]` contains a supercritical bifurcation - hence, the equation has three solutions for `t < 2`, and I have to pick one solution depending on the sign of x. However, I have figured out that a simple way to get around this problem, is to use that `y = Tanh[(2y + x)/t]` is symmetric around `x = 0`, and then simply just doing the 3D plot in two halves up to `x = +/- 0.001`.

Now, I have succeeded in plotting `y = Tanh[(2y + x)/t]` on my own with no problems - however, when I try to plot `z = -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2y + x)/t]]` as best as I can, I get a host of error messages and a beautiful surface plot that looks very close to correct - yet, but I can tell from cuts through the surface that the plot simply isn't correct, because the slope of z just isn't fulfilling `y = - ∂z/∂x`.

I am very much a noob at Mathematica, so I have done the best I could by bodging and tinkering - but I am completely stomped as to whether I am missing something mathematically or whether it is Mathematica problem, because I am not plugging y correctly into z. Could anybody possibly show me the correct way of doing this 3D plot of z, because I think I just may be in over my head? <:)

**Addition:**

I thought I'd better post the code I have used:

```
g[x_, t_] := y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t], {y, -5}];
p1 = ContourPlot3D[ z == - t * Log[2*Cosh[(2 g[x, t] + x)/t]] , 
{t, 0.001, 3}, {x, -1.5, -0.001}, {z, -4.0, -1.0}, 
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{t, x, z}, 
Evaluate[  D[z + t * Log[2*Cosh[(2 g[x, t] + x)/t]], z]]    ]}, 
Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> Lighter /@ ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, 
AxesLabel -> {t, x, z}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

k[x_, t_] := y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t], {y, 5}];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[ z == - t * Log[2*Cosh[(2 k[x, t] + x)/t]] , 
{t, 0.001, 3}, {x, 0.001, 1.5}, {z, -4.0, -1.0}, 
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{t, x, z}, 
Evaluate[  D[z + t * Log[2*Cosh[(2 k[x, t] + x)/t]], z]]    ]}, 
Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> Lighter /@ ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, 
AxesLabel -> {t, x, z}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {{0.0, 3.0}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-4.0, -1.0}}, 
ViewPoint -> {0.9*Pi, -0.45*Pi, 1.05*Pi} ]
```

As I wrote above, this is the product of quite a bit of tinkering and bodging because I am very new to this, so I am not completely sure what everything is doing - this just seems to do the trick. The main errors I am getting are: `FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {-5.-1.\ Tanh[(-10.+x)/t]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y} = {-5.}."` and `ReplaceAll::reps: "{FindRoot[y==Tanh[(2\y+x)/t],{y,-5}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."` - but I am not sure what to make of them.

Comment: Your errors are coming from `ContourPlot3D` attempting to evaluate `g` with symbolic arguments. You need to define `g` so that it only takes numeric arguments, like `g[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := blah`. The same goes for `k` obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the technique I used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23565/17) could be applied to your question as well.

```
paraRegion = ContourPlot3D[
  y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t], (* the constraint on x, y, t *)
  {x, -2, 2},
  {y, -1, 1},
  {t, 0, 2},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {x, y, t})]
```

[image: parameters region]

```
Cases[paraRegion,
   GraphicsComplex[pts_, others_,
     opts1___, VertexNormals -> vn_, opts2___] :>
    GraphicsComplex[
     Function[{x, y, t},
       {x, y, -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2 y + x)/t]]} (* the surface in xyz space *)
       ] @@@ pts,
     others, opts1, opts2], ∞][[1]] //
 Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}), 
   PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image: xyz surface]

**Edit:**

To illustrate the surface indeed fulfills $y=-\partial_x z$ (and actually a [*ruled surface*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface)), we can add options as following to the `ContourPlot3D` for `paraRegion` to emphasize the feature:

```
ContourStyle -> None,
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
Mesh -> {10, 20},
MeshStyle -> {Gray, Directive[Darker[Blue], Thick]}
```

which give

[image: mesh graph]

**Edit 2:**

According to OP's request in the comment, to plot the surface in $txz$ space, there is no essential difference. We can just change the parametric equations in $xyz$ space in the line I marked with `(* the surface in xyz space *)` to the equations in $txz$ space, that is

```
{t, x, -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2 y + x)/t]]}
```

[image: txz plot]

The key point is, once we have a self-contained feasible set $\left\{\boldsymbol{p}\mid\boldsymbol{p}=(t,x,y,z)\land F(t,x,y,z)=0\right\}$ (*e.g.* the points on the surface of `paraRegion` along the relation `z == f[x, y, t]`), it's up to us in which space we'd like to represent it - just strip out the extra dimension and it's done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - and it is indeed precisely with ContourPlot3D I managed to plot y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t]. However, it is z = -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2y + x)/t]] I am trying to plot, where I wish to use y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t] to deliver the values of y to z. I have added the code I have used, for the surface I get out (unfortunately I can't post pictures yet), that I am fairly certain is close to correct but not quite.

Comment: @nielsen The second and third plots are indeed the region (surface) `z = -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2y + x)/t]]` in $xyz$ space, which is constrained by `y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t]`. You might want to refer to the linked answer for more technique detail about this method.

Comment: Aha - now I see what you are doing, I didn't notice that it was (x,y,z) space - and that is a very elegant way of way of showing that `z = ∂y/∂x` is held up. I really like that. But how do I then plot (t,x,z) space - because your solution seems to utilize that we can just plug `z == -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2y + x)/t]]` directly into Function?

Comment: @nielsen Please see my last edit, also the explanation at the end.

Comment: I actuallly tried something like that - but apparently I changed too much, because I changed the `{x, y, t}` declaration in front too. And if I change the ranges to `{t,0,3}, {y,-1.5,1.5}, {x, -1.5,1.5}` then I actually get precisely the plot I got with my own first method - so it would seem that even my own original attempt was correct. Can I just ask - the plot I get from your method has an extra 'top' so to speak (roughly the righthand z > -2 side in your last plot), are those imaginary solutions and is there a way to exclude those?

Comment: @nielsen Sorry I'm not quite following you about *imaginary solutions*. But you should notice that as the range of $\tanh$ is $\mathopen{]}-1,1\mathclose{[}$, there is no point to take points where $y>1$ or $y<-1$.

Answer (score 1):

One can adapt (simplify somewhat) [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26736/transcendental-equation-with-contourplot3d/26779#26779) to this case.

It will be convenient to compute a `NormalsFunction` and to parametrize the plot in terms of `y` as defined by zero set of `F = t ArcTanh[y] - (2*y + x)` (which is computed by `g` and `k` in the OP from the equivalent equation `y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/t]`).

**Surface normal function**

From `F == 0`, we can compute $\partial y/\partial t$ (`dydt`) and  $\partial y/\partial x$ (`dydx`).  These can be plugged into the gradient (normal) of the surface `z == -t*Log[2*Cosh[(2 y[t, x] + x)/t]]`, the normal can be multiplied by a scalar, both to clear the denominator and to get it to point "up" (with respect to `z`).  Then we can apply a couple of identities and simplify.

```
F = t ArcTanh[y] - (2*y + x);
dydt = -D[F, t]/D[F, y];
dydx = -D[F, x]/D[F, y];

2 t (-2 + t + 2 y^2)*
     D[z + t*Log[2*Cosh[(2 y[t, x] + x)/t]], {{t, x, z}}] /.
        {Derivative[1, 0][y][t, x] -> dydt, Derivative[0, 1][y][t, x] -> dydx, 
              Cosh[u_] :> 1/Sqrt[1 - Tanh[u]^2]} /. y[t, x] -> y /. 
          Tanh[(x + 2 y)/t] -> y // PowerExpand // Expand // FullSimplify

(* {-2 y (x + 2 y) (-2 + t + 2 y^2) +
       t (4 y (-1 + y^2) ArcTanh[y] + t Log[4] + (-1 + y^2) Log[16] -
          (-2 + t + 2 y^2) Log[1 - y^2]), 
    2 t^2 y,
    2 t (-2 + t + 2 y^2)} *)
```

The formula from this output may be used to define a surface normal function for plotting:

```
normalsFn = 
  Compile[{t, x, y},
    {-2 y (x + 2 y) (-2 + t + 2 y^2) +
         t (4 y (-1 + y^2) ArcTanh[y] + t Log[4] + (-1 + y^2) Log[16] -
            (-2 + t + 2 y^2) Log[1 - y^2]), 
     2 t^2 y,
     2 t (-2 + t + 2 y^2)} ];
```

**Parametrization**

There is a bifurcation where the `y` partial of `F` is zero.  We can solve `F == 0` for `x` in terms of `y` and `t`; it happens that `x` is a linear function of `t`, which makes the problem quite tractable.  We can use this solution to find a parametrization of `t`, `x`, such that the bifurcation happens when `u == 0`, and the end points `u == -1` and `u == 1` correspond to `t == 0` and `t = 3` respectively.

The functions `tP`, `xP`, `zP` parametrize the `t`, `x`, `z` coordinates of the surface in terms of `y` and a parameter `u`.
We use some utility functions in defining them:

- `xOFty`:  returns `x` for a given `t`, `y`;
- `tOFxy`: returns `t` for a given `x`, `y`;
- `xBrOFy`: returns the `x` coordinate on the bifurcation curve for a given `y`.

We give different definitions of `tP` and `xP` depending on the side of the bifurcation curve. (See also [the linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26736/transcendental-equation-with-contourplot3d/26779#26779).)  We define the parametrization in terms of the domain `{{tMin, tMax}, {xMin, xMax}}`, for the purposes of rescaling, which domain is taken from the OP.

```
xOFty[t_, y_] := Evaluate[x /. Simplify@First@Solve[F == 0, x]];
tOFxy[x_, y_] := Evaluate[t /. Simplify@First@Solve[F == 0, t]];
xBrOFy[y_] := Evaluate[x /. Simplify@First@Solve[F == 0 /. First@Solve[D[F, y] == 0, t], x]];

Clear[xP, tP, zP];
xP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u >= 0 && y >= 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {xBrOFy[y], Min[x2, xOFty[t2, y]]}];
xP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u >= 0 && y < 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {xBrOFy[y], Max[x1, xOFty[t2, y]]}];
xP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u < 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {-1, 0}, {-2 y, xBrOFy[y]}];

tP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u >= 0 && y == 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {2, t2}];
tP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u < 0 && y == 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {-1, 0}, {t1, 2}];
tP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; -1 < y < 1 := 
  tOFxy[xP[u, y, {{t1, t2}, {x1, x2}}], y];

zP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] := -tP[u, y, {{t1, t2}, {x1, x2}}] *
   Log[2*Cosh[(2 y + xP[u, y, {{t1, t2}, {x1, x2}}]) / tP[u, y, {{t1, t2}, {x1, x2}}]]];

{tMin, tMax} = {0, 3}; {xMin, xMax} = {-2, 2};
domain = {{tMin, tMax}, {xMin, xMax}};
param[u_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] /; -1 < y < 1 :=
   {tP[u, y, domain], xP[u, y, domain], zP[u, y, domain]};
```

**Plots**

As before (in my other answer), we need more plot points near `y == -1` and `y == 1`, so we use `Sin[(Pi/2) v]` to interpolate between `-1`, `+1`.  (We use it for the sake of convenience.)

*The whole surface.*  To get good result near `y == -1` and `y == 1`, we increase `WorkingPrecision` a little.

```
ParametricPlot3D[param[u, Sin[(Pi/2) v]],
 {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, NormalsFunction -> (normalsFn[#1, #2, Sin[(Pi/2) #5]] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {t, x, z}, ImageSize -> 300, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image: Whole surface]

*The part indicated in the OP.*  We can restrict the plot with a slight redefinition of `xP` (keeping the other definitions) and limiting the domain of the parameter `u`; however, over this domain, we do not need to increase `WorkingPrecision`.

```
xP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u >= 0 && y >= 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {(*xBrOFy[y]*)0, Min[x2, xOFty[t2, y]]}];
xP[u_, y_, {{t1_, t2_}, {x1_, x2_}}] /; u >= 0 && y < 0 := 
  Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {(*xBrOFy[y]*)0, Max[x1, xOFty[t2, y]]}];

ParametricPlot3D[param[u, Sin[(Pi/2) v]],
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, -1, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, NormalsFunction -> (normalsFn[#1, #2, Sin[(Pi/2) #5]] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {t, x, z}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]