# Calculate and plot the tangent hyperplane to a function of three variables

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

If

```
f:= x^3 + y*x*z - z^2 + x*z
```

and if `{{1,2,1},{2,7,8},{6,0,2},{9,1,1}}` are points, how can I find the tangent plane to `f` at the four points in the same time.

I saw some codes to calculate the tangent , for example,

```
tg[f_, x_, p_] := (f'[x] /. x -> p) (x - p) + f[p]
q = #^3 - 3 #^2 &;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{q[x], tg[q, u, m] /. u -> x}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{m, q[m]}]}], {m, -1, 1, 
  0.01}]
```

but  I am confused this did not answer my question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Before you come to answering this question in Mathematica, can you map out a plan of how to solve this issue - some pseudocode?  Mathematically, what would you need, which derivatives?  And what do you mean exactly by "tangent" - a plane or a line?  Do you know what the code you pasted does?

Comment: If `f` is a function of three variables, then wouldn't the tangent be three dimensional as well?  I'm just thinking about the tangent to `f[x]` is a line, and the tangent to `f[x,y]` is a plane.

Comment: The solution would come from applying the technique [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx), which shows how to find the plane tangent to a surface, to four dimensions instead of three - sounds like a fun homework problem.

Comment: @Jason, yes, a hyperplane would be a 3D manifold.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentPlane.html) and [here](http://www.math.brown.edu/~banchoff/howison/ma35labs-static-latest/32p1.html)

```
f := x^3 + y*x*z - z^2 + x*z

tangent[point_] := ({x, y, z} - point).(D[f, {{x, y, z}}] /. 
     Thread[{x, y, z} -> point]) + (f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> point])
```

(thanks to J.M. for the improvement here)

You can get the tangent for the four points via

```
(tangent /@ {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 7, 8}, {6, 0, 2}, {9, 1, 1}}) // TableForm
```

[image]

Since this is a function of three variables, the only way I can think to plot it is using a [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate[tangent[{6, 0, 2}]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: A bit shorter: `tangent[point_] := ({x, y, z} - point).(D[f, {{x, y, z}}] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> point]) + (f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> point])` Dot products and gradients are nice. :)

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate points made in comments:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y*x*z - z^2 + x*z
dat = {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 7, 8}, {6, 0, 2}, {9, 1, 1}};
tpl[x_, y_, z_, p_, q_, r_] := 
 With[{g = Grad[f[a, b, c], {a, b, c}] /. {a -> x, b -> y, c -> z}},
  g.{p - x, q - y, r - z} == 0
  ]
func[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Show[ContourPlot3D[
   f[x, y, z] == f[a, b, c], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
    Mesh -> False, PlotLabel -> f[x, y, z] == f[a, b, c]],
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{a, b, c}]}]]
```

The surfaces through points and the tangent plane to points:

```
planes = ContourPlot3D[#, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
     Mesh -> None, 
     ContourStyle -> {Pink, Opacity[0.5]}] & /@ (tpl[##, x, y, z] & @@@
      dat);
surfaces = func @@@ dat;
Grid[Partition[MapThread[Show[#1, #2] &, {surfaces, planes}], 2]]
```

[image]

This could have been done in a  much neater way but I hope supports comments.

Comment: @JasonB I think we are doing the same thing in slightly different ways. I am just plotting surface that passes through given point, the point and using the gradient as normal vector for tangent plane

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  Still incredibly hard to visualize four-dimensional objects - even as contour plots.  Even here - how do we see that the planes are tangential to the surfaces?  They seem to go through them

Comment: @JasonB I cannot visualise 4D or above in my imagination but the points let us plot a contour in 3D space and then we can play a bit...:)

Comment: Right - so I guess it's true that the 3D contours to a tangent hyperplane are not tangent to 3D contours of the surface, even when the same contour value is used.  (you can tell I'm not a mathematician or I'd have known that I suppose)

Comment: @Jason: "Even here - how do we see that the planes are tangential to the surfaces?" I can't implement the idea right now, but maybe either you or ubpdqn can pursue it. Consider a lower dimensional analogy: if you slice a usual 3D surface and its tangent plane with a plane that passes through the point of tangency, you will see the image of some curve and some line that is tangent to it. It looks to me that it can be done for higher dimensions. (I used an idea like that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23582).)

Comment: @J.M. Something like _"Consider a sphere in R^3 and find a line tangent to two points `at the same time`"_? :)

Comment: @bel, no, that's an *impossible* problem; very different species. :P

Comment: @J.M. That's what is written in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, it applies the general Taylor formula:

[image]

She can be coded as follows (m = 1 -> tangent):

```
taylorPolynom[point_] := Sum[
  1/j! Nest[(vars - point).# &, 
     D[f[vars], {vars, j}] /. Thread[vars -> point], j], {j, 0, m}]

vars = {x, y, z};
f[vars_] = x^3 + y*x*z - z^2 + x*z;
m = 1;
```

And with the points we get:

```
taylorPolynom /@ {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 7, 8}, {6, 0, 2}, {9, 1,1}} 
{6 (-1 + x) + y + z,
 72 + 76 (-2 + x) + 16 (-7 + y),
 224 + 110 (-6 + x) + 12 y + 2 (-2 + z),
 746 + 245 (-9 + x) + 9 (-1 + y) + 16 (-1 + z)}
```

The same result as the above solutions, but this solution is generally valid for each dimension.