# Plot implicit function with intermediate variable

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, variable-definitions, regions

**Cross-posted [in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2440625).**

---

Here, I intend to plot a 3D picture of

[image]

with two implicit functions

[image]

where $x, y, t, \xi, \eta$, are variables. Of course, these variables can be constrained to certain interval that will guarantee the function to be well-posed. My code is attached below.

How can I draw this one?

```
x == ξ - 0.5 Tanh[ξ - 0.3 t] - Tanh[ξ - 0.1 t] - 
   1.5 Tanh[ξ + 0.1 t];

y == η - 1.5 Tanh[η];

Plot3D[-((
  1350.` Sech[η]^2 Tanh[η] (1.` Sech[0.1 t - ξ]^2 Tanh[
       0.1 t - ξ] + 
     0.6` Sech[0.3 t - ξ]^2 Tanh[0.3 t - ξ] + 
     1.6` Sech[0.1 t + ξ]^2 Tanh[0.1 t + ξ]))/((1 - 
     1.5 Sech[η]^2) (1 - Sech[0.1 t - ξ]^2 - 
     0.5 Sech[0.3 t - ξ]^2 - 
     1.5 Sech[0.1 t + ξ]^2) (0.3 Sech[η]^2 + 
     0.5 Sech[0.1 t - ξ]^2 + 0.3 Sech[0.3 t - ξ]^2 - 
     0.8` Sech[0.1 t + ξ]^2)^2)), {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium]}]
```

Comment: Many issues with your syntax.  Your `==` statements are not assignment statements; they are boolean statements:  `x` and `y` will not be assigned a value. Your `Plot3D` is not a function of `x` and `y` so nothing will plot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, even ``==" is replaced by ``=", it can not work too. Here, ``x == ξ - 0.5 Tanh[ξ - 0.3 t] - Tanh[ξ - 0.1 t] - 
   1.5 Tanh[ξ + 0.1 t]; y == η - 1.5 Tanh[η];'' means two constrains, particualy.

Comment: As @Edmund said, the function you are trying to plot is a function of `t`, `ξ` and `η` and not `x` and `y`. This means that unless they are in turn functions of `x` and `y` you cannot plot them as a function of`x` and `y`. In order to give a 3D plot you would also need to fix one of the variables i.e. `t`, or `ξ` .

Comment: It is exactly the point that \xi and \eta can not be solved analytically, which cause the problem.

Comment: CrossPost: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2440625

Comment: [My old answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23565/17) might be related. Basically you can plot your main function against `ξ` and `η`, then use your `x == f[ξ]` and `y == g[η]` relationship (maybe through `Plot` or numerical procedure) to remap `ξ, η` coordinates to `x, y` in the previously finished 3D surface graphic (say through `ReplaceAll`).